# When a limit does not exist, can its derivative be found?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

[image]

I am learning derivatives of complex numbers (functions, actually) and what a learned community member pointed to me was that there is a subtle difference between finding derivatives of real numbers.

He said that the derivative of a complex function can be calculated iff it satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations. Which means, limit at the point $z$ exists.

Back to **reals**. Have a look at the diagram above.
I can calculate derivatives in both the cases. The 'mechanical' derivative using chain rule, quotient rule, product rule, etc. The derivative will **fail** if I plug in x = 13 (in both the cases) but for all other values of $x$, I can calculate the derivative (slope).
In other words, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x = 13$.

The same concept applies in case of complex functions, right ?
You use Cauchy Riemann equations to see if $f(z)$ is differentiable at a given $z$. Even if it is not differentiable, I can still calculate the derivative mechanically, right ? And the derivative will **fail** if I plug in the given $z$ at which it was not differentiable

Please clarify.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  In all cases where you can correctly apply the chain rule, quotient rule, product rule etc  (whether real or complex), the derivative will exist.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well .. what I am asking is **Cauchy Reiman only shows if function is differentiable for a given z. Derivative can still be found if a given value of z fails Cauchy Reiman** right ?

Comment: The "learned" community member never said that iif...he said that *if* $f$ is differentiable at $z$, then it satisfies the C.R. equations at $z$. The converse needs more care...

Comment: aaargh .. let's cut the crap. Someone please calculate the derivative of $f(z) = z^3 + 2z^2 -6i$ @Avitus :p

Comment: To do that check the derivatives (using the limit definition as exercise) of the complex functions $g(z)=z^3$, $h(z)=2z^2$ and $r(z)=-6i$. The functions are differentiable for all $z\in\mathbb C$ and the results are what you get applying "mechanically" the rules of differentiation of REAL functions to the complex functions $g$, $h$ and $r$. The result $f'(z)$ is just the sum, as differentiation is linear. The mechanical application of the rules of real differentiation to the complex case is justified by differentiability of the functions $g$, $h$ and $r$.

Comment: @Avitus So derivative of a complex function is basically the same as that of real function. *Differentiability at z is a different issue. I am excluding that , for now. But without a specific value for z, the process is the same*

Comment: The derivative of $z^3 + 2 z^2 - 6 i$ is $3 z^2 + 4 z$, of course.  In practice you almost never use the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: @RobertIsrael We do in college though .. :-D

Comment: In particular, if you build a function up from differentiable functions (such as $z$) using the standard arithmetic operations, the result will always be differentiable where it is defined (e.g. avoiding division by $0$).  Caution must be exercised for things like logarithms and non-integer powers where you can run into branch cuts, but otherwise all is fine.

Comment: In the complex case you have the mechanical application of the rules of real differentiation, this is true (when differentiability is satisfied). What you lose is the geometric flavor, however. Once you can move through $f_x$ , $f_y$ and $f'(z)$ you are done! ps: are you in college? You deal with advanced topics :)

Comment: @Avitus Yes, I am in college ! But uh ... I dont like the way my professors teach. ;-)

Comment: Ok, but always respect your teachers, raise questions, compare your notes with books and in case of support ask questions on Math.SE. This is a good way to learn!

Comment: @Avitus Ah , well .. situation in my country is sooo different. If you meet me in chat someday, I will tell you :-) For now, I am doing a sum on $f(z)$. I will post my workings here so stay tuned ! Get ready to check my working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the captions of the pictures, I think we should still talk about real derivatives for a bit.

### Brief answer

Neither of functions depicted in your graphs are going to be differentiable at the discontinuities depicted. After you fill in a removable discontinuity of a function like the one on the left, it could be either differentiable or nondifferentiable at the point. Jump discontinuities of functions on the real line are always nondifferentiable, but they might have one-sided derivatives that are well-defined.

### Longer anwer

First of all, remember that the derivative at a point is, intuitively, a "limit of slopes as calculated from the left and from the right." From the left you take a limit of $\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$ over very small positive values of $h$, and on the right the same happens with $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. (It can be the case that both of these can be defined, but they don't match and in that case, the derivative isn't defined at that point.)

Notice also that it is critical for $f(x)$ to be defined to carry out these computations, and so you won't get anywhere at all without settling on a value for $f(x)$. If you insist that there's no value for $f(x)$, then the slope is formally undefined. If you are willing to fill in removable discontinuities, though, you can proceed. The derivative may or may not exist after the point is filled in (consider $f(x)=|x|$ with the $x=0$ point removed/replaced.)

That leaves the case of the jump discontinuity, which you've depicted in the right hand picture. Jump discontinuities always make one of the slope limits on the right or on the left jump to infinity. Here's what I mean. Suppose $f(x)$ is anywhere exept filling in the lower circle in your right hand picture. Then as you shrink $h$ in $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, the associated picture is that of a line which always lies on $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+h,f(x+h)$, which lies on the branch on the right. You see as $h$ shrinks, $x+h$ approaches $x$ from the right. Since $f(x)$ is not on that lower empty circle, this line tips ever more steeply as $h$ shrinks. Thus its slope goes to either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, and the slope there is undefined.

If $f(x)$ happened to land on that empty lower right circle, then you are guaranteed it wouldn't land on the upper left circle, so you would then deduce that the slope estimate from the left would go off to infinity, and the derivative at the point would again not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I realize this answer isn't going down the path of real/complex differentiability as your question suggested, but I just felt that based on the captions of the diagram, the misunderstanding was more primitive than that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with a simple example:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+1 & \text{if $x>0$}\\
0 & \text{if $x=0$}\\
x-1 & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
If you compute the derivative “mechanically”, you get
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x>0$}\\
1 & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
and you might be tempted to say that $f$ is also differentiable at $0$ with derivative $1$, but this would be wrong.

A necessary condition for a function to be differentiable at a point $a$ is that it's continuous at $a$, but the function $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

The proof is simple: if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=l
$$
exists (finite). Therefore you can compute
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)
&=\lim_{x\to a}\left(f(a)+\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}(x-a)\right)\\
&=f(a)+\left(\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)
\left(\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)\right)\\
&=f(a)+l\cdot0=f(a)
\end{align}
because of well known theorems on limits.

Notice that this works in precisely the same way for complex functions; in both cases the function needs to be defined in some neighborhood of $a$ (for instance an open interval containing $a$ in the real case, an open disk containing $a$ in the complex case).

The Cauchy-Riemann equations are a useful tool, but still the definition for the derivative of a complex function $f$ can be given in the same way as in the real case: the complex function $f$, defined in an open neighborhood of $a\in\mathbb{C}$, is differentiable at $a$ if (and only if)
$$
\lim_{z\to a}\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}
$$
exists (finite).